# Material Design Menu Item

Tags: android, material-design, menuitem, material-components-android

So here I thought after implementing Material Design everything would be just like it says in the guideline. But when I used a menu item with only a title (THE RIGHT ONE, NOT HOME ICON), it's not the same as what it would like in the guideline :

[image: what I expect]

Instead, it's still like this :

[image: what I get]

Or do I have to create a custom view to have a menu item like that? if so, how?
Thank you for your help..

Comment: I believe you are referring to Contextual Action Bar (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB)

Comment: @PavelDudka nope, what I'm asking is the Menu Item in the right one..I've seen the material design guideline and it all shows their menu item's positioning like that. Is it a custom view?

Comment: Oh, I see. Not sure about padding, but text size for menu item can be configured via `android:actionMenuTextAppearance` attribute in your theme

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);` in the onCreate method of your activity

Or if you are using toolbar, you can do the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Comment: I think you're mistaken my question..what I'm asking is the Menu Item in the right one, not the home icon..